# Python raspberry pi serial sim868 Login incorrect

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

why sometime it is working?

I try to call at command.

How can I fix it?

```
import serial
import time
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200, timeout=1)
port.write('AT'+'\r\n')
print port.read(10)
time.sleep(.1)
```

output 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the serial port is kept open and you need to close it before accessing it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the delay *before* the read:

```
time.sleep(.1)
print port.read(10)
```